# Django finding non-existent changes to a model after each migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

After running `python manage.py migrate`, Django will consistently return:

`Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.`

Hmm that's funny, I don't remember making a change. 
`python manage.py makemigrations --dry-run --verbosity=3`

```
Generated by Django 1.11 on 2017-0x-xx xx:xx
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django_cryptography.fields


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
       ('myApp', '0019_auto_xxxxxxx_xx'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='myModel',
            name='encrypted_field',
            field=django_cryptography.fields.encrypt(models.CharField(verbose_name=models.CharField(verbose_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Encrypted Field')))),
    ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='myModel',
            name='second_encrypted_field',
            field=django_cryptography.fields.encrypt(models.CharField(verbose_name=models.CharField(verbose_name=models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Second encrypted field')))),
    ),
]
```

That would be fine, but the exact same AlterField() was run in `0018_auto`.  I've tested it out on a couple systems, even tried making these migrations for real and applying but, but the warning keeps coming back in `0020_auto`.

`myModel.__str__` does reference one of those encrypted fields, which I think is what's causing the recursion in the migration.  Still, I can't understand why that would make Django keep picking them up.

Any idea what could be causing this? Is it a bug? Something having to do with the nature of `django_cryptography`? Something else?